# How to calculate a new column from a large Dataframe using Dictionary in a custom function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe df with 700 million rows and three columns in the following format

```
  key_x key_y  num
0 1       1    111.111
1 1       2    222.222
2 1       3    333.333
:
```

I have a dictionary dict where all values in key_x and key_y are stored as keys

I need to create a new column such that, for each row in df

```
df['result'] =  df['num'] /( dict[key_x] * dict[key_y])
```

My current approach is to vectorize as the following:

```
def find_res(key_x,key_y,num):
    return num/(dict[key_x]*row_dict[key_y])

df["result"] = np.vectorize(find_res)(df["key"],df["key_y"],df["num"])
```

However this approach is too slow. I have a RAM of around 500GB, so mem is not an issue. Is there an more efficient method to perform the same operation?

Comment: Please post your expected output based on sample input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`:

```
df['result'] = df['num'] / (df['key_x'].map(your_dict) * df['key_y'].map(your_dict) )
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll need to do a speed comparison between the two implementations on some input data